# Should article preview pages be crawled and indexed by search engines?

Tags: seo, search-engines, web-crawlers, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

I have a page called "all articles" that loads previews of articles using AJAX.  Because of that, the content won't be visible to search engines, so the page would be considered "poor content".

Since I have a page for each article, I think that it would be better not to crawl and index this page at all. Is it good practice to exclude it or will it affect my website ranking somehow since I have links pointing to this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll lose some credit by noindexing a page that has links.

Let Google index it and attribute link equity. Because it's a navigation page you'll likely find it does just fine.

**Explanation:**
Google as a search engine works hard on making sure that users get the pages they want. This navigation page clearly has value if users are finding it via Google and you've got lots of links to it. Just because Google isn't able to determine exactly what the value of the content is at a glance doesn't mean you'll be hit with some invisible penalty. It simply means you won't get as much credit as a more transparent static page.